# retrieve only certain values from an object in a nested array?

Tags: php, arrays, object

OK i have the following array:

```
array(2) {
  ["campaigns"]=>
  array(50) {
    [0]=>
    object(Campaign)#2122 (48) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(26) "FOO"
      ["id"]=>
      string(74) "****************"
      ["link"]=>
      string(44) "/ws/"
      ["status"]=>
      string(4) "Sent"
      ["lists"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["fromAddress"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["replyAddress"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["archiveStatus"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["archiveUrl"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["urls"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    object(Campaign)#2122 (48) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(26) "FOO"
      ["id"]=>
      string(74) "****************"
      ["link"]=>
      string(44) "/ws/"
      ["status"]=>
      string(4) "Sent"
      ["lists"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["fromAddress"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["replyAddress"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["archiveStatus"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["archiveUrl"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["urls"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
    [2]=>
    object(Campaign)#2122 (48) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(26) "FOO"
      ["id"]=>
      string(74) "****************"
      ["link"]=>
      string(44) "/ws/"
      ["status"]=>
      string(4) "Sent"
      ["lists"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["fromAddress"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["replyAddress"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["archiveStatus"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["archiveUrl"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["urls"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I'm using this is traverse it and echo all of the object contents:

```
    foreach ($getallCampaigns as $tableName => $tableData) { // Loop outer array
  foreach ($tableData as $row) { // Loop table rows
    $cols = $vals = array();
    foreach ($row as $col => $val) { // Loop this row
      $cols[] = $col;
      $vals[] = $val; // You may need to escape this before using it in a query...
      echo '<li>'.$col.': '. $val .'</li>';
    }
  }
}
```

My queston is how do i print only the ['name'] and the ['id'] not the whole object?

Comment: Lose the entire loop `foreach($row as $col => $val)` and just replace it with `echo $row->name . ' ' . $row->id;` surround with your `<li>` as necessary. Always recommended to wrap in `htmlspecialchars()` to escape for HTML output...

Comment: do you want to put it as an answer and I'll happily accpet

Comment: Ok, I converted to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire innermost loop is unnecessary if you only wish to get two properties out of it. What it is doing is iterating the object properties via `foreach` and writing them all. It is objects you're iterating over, so use `->` and take only the properties you need.

```
foreach ($getallCampaigns as $tableName => $tableData) { // Loop outer array
  foreach ($tableData as $row) { // Loop table rows
    // The entire inner loop is unneeded.
    // Use htmlspecialchars() to escape as HTML output, always recommended
    echo '<li>Name:' . htmlspecialchars($row->name) . '</li><li>ID: ' . htmlspecialchars($row->id) . '</li>';
  }
}
```